# Como reordenar indicadores dentro de un layout en Android

Tags: android

Necesito reordenar la ubicación de los indicadores en mi pantalla y no consigo hacerlo correctamente, tengo un listview, edittext a un botón, el edittext y el boton están agrupadas de tal manera que se puede ocultar y hacerlo visible mediante código.

Cuando está habilitado la visibilidad del edittext y el botón en la pantalla debe de mostrarse el listview, el edittext y el botón y cuando esta se deshabilita en toda la pantalla solo se debe de mostrar el listview

Esto es lo que tengo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y esto es lo que necesito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui esta el archivo XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menuSpecialKey"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_margin="0dip"
    android:tag="key code block"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:tag="Write block"
        >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et1_WriteValues"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bt1_SendButton"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:background="@drawable/corner_roud_edittext"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bt1_SendButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_bg_rounded_corners"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:text="SEND"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_msg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estas posicionando los elementos. El contenedor menuSpecialKey tienes que alinearlo al *bottom* del padre, y la lista ponerla encima de este contenedor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
  tools:context=".MainActivity"
  tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/menuSpecialKey"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_margin="0dip"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:tag="key code block"
      >
      <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_margin="0dip"
        android:tag="Write block"
        >

        <EditText
          android:id="@+id/et1_WriteValues"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="45dp"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bt1_SendButton"
          android:layout_weight="0.7"
          android:background="@drawable/corner_roud_edittext"
          android:inputType="textCapSentences|textAutoCorrect"
          android:paddingLeft="15dp"
          android:paddingRight="15dp" />

        <Button
          android:id="@+id/bt1_SendButton"
          android:layout_width="50dp"
          android:layout_height="50dp"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
          android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
          android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
          android:background="@drawable/button_bg_rounded_corners"
          android:gravity="center"
          android:scaleType="centerInside"
          android:text="SEND"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

      </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list_msg"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
      android:layout_above="@+id/menuSpecialKey"
      android:divider="@null"
      android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent"
      android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" />

  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Como apunte el layout se puede simplificar mucho más, no hace falta tener tantos contenedores. Otro apunte importante es cambiar ListView por RecyclerView, ya no debería usarse ListView ya que el Recycler es mucho más eficiente.

Un saludo.